# Process of turning groups of animation nodes into templates for easy reuse?

Tags: python, add-on, animation-nodes

I have been recreating those gifs from the official doc of animation node, which made me question how do you package a awesome animation you made into a new node for later use? I basically want to turn all the panel in below screen shot into one. Is it do it able? Is it recommended? Whats the best way to approach this? I know python I just don't know where I can get more info on this.

Answer (score 1):

A part of a node tree can be made reusable by encapsulating it in a [subprogram](https://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/subprograms/index.html), something analogous to functions in python. One can create multiple subprograms in a node tree and save it in an empty blend file, this file can act as a module where if one wants to use the subprograms defined there one would simply append the node tree previously defined. Note that subprograms can be invoked across node trees, so no further interaction from the user is required after appending the node tree.

If you want to go the extra mile and implement your own nodes in Animation Nodes using Python and Cython, have a look at the [Developer's Guide](https://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev_guide/index.html).

Comment: Is this really only way to do this? I've recently started with some simple generator test and I already have 9 groups where 6 are general purpose reusable, 1 generates some specific kind of object and 2 are completely no-reusable, and if I want to reuse a single group from the file, I would see all of those in single, randomly ordered list :( I've considered to use python, but I've stopped the reading after "you have to restart the blender" sentence.

Comment: @PawełAudionysos Well just put them in different files.

Comment: But the 1 group use all 8 other groups. Will this work?

Comment: @PawełAudionysos I see, In which case, you will have to append all of them. You can use the search menu to search for their name (Only in the latest version) and add them.